# How do I prevent background color from over-flowing into the rows padding?

Tags: html, css

I have a header row with an image in it that occupies 8 out of the 12 columns. I need the background color behind the image and the remaining 4 columns to be white - which is different from the body color. First I tried to just add the bg color to the row, but the white overflowed into the padding. Then I tried to add a child div that wraps the columns but I got the problem:

[image]

You can see that white gap to the right of the image. Here is what I'm trying to achieve:

[image]

See how there is no white to the left of the image, how do I do that in css and html?

**Edit: adding some code**

html:

```
  <header class="row"> 
    <div class="header-wrapper clearfix">
      <div class="small-8 columns">
        <img src="images/header-logo.png">
      </div>
      <div class="small-4 columns orbit-columns">
        <img src="images/orbit/new-port-richey-office.jpg" alt="">
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>
```

scss:

```
header.row {
   // background-color: $white;
   .header-wrapper {
      background-color: $white;
      margin-left: -0.9375rem;
      margin-right: -0.9375rem;
   }
}
```

Comment: Can we see some html and css? or perhaps a JSFiddle?

Comment: Please post some code.

Comment: Padding means how much space you want to leave before the content starts which means it's a part of your content. If you don't want the space, I'd say remove left padding or use negative margin equivalent to padding on the image.

Comment: @LokeshSuthar For some reason, I thought that changing the padding of foundation's columns would break my layout, but it seems be working.

Comment: Remove the padding and use the margin instead,

Comment: Columns' widths are calculated in % and it shouldn't break until you increase the padding or margin. removing it should be fine.